How to securely request new access token with refresh token from SPA (Single Page Javascript Browser App)
We use the Firebase JS SDK for our React App. The whole sign-in flow is great and secure. Uses a middleware auth domain handler which Firebase uses to exchange codes and what's not.
However, once authenticated, the SDK saves the Web API key, refresh token, and all other session credentials and user data in the browser's IndexDB. Technically, anyone can manually get hold of these credentials (or use a scraping script which runs in the context of the open webpage)
Saving to IndexDB: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/core/persistence/persistence_user_manager.ts#L103
The only protection I see Firebase having in place is that it only allows requests of a specific client_id to come from the registered origins of that client. And luckily, Origin is one of the only HTTP Headers that is impossible to set or modify programmatically.
Isn't all of this discouraged in the OAuth guidelines? Since big firms and SDKs are storing credentials in the browser storage, is this an accepted vulnerability for smooth UX?

I'm not certain (as the details inside the question are sparse), but are you asking a variant of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public?

API keys are not part of the OAuth spec. If you had an API key to access protected resources on the resource server, you wouldn't need OAuth.
OAuth is for accessing protected resources on behalf of a user. The "Auth" in OAuth refers to authorization. As in, the user needs to authorize the client, your app, to access their data or perform actions on their behalf.
I'm not sure what you're talking about with running a scraping script because you visited a page on a webpage. Yes, if a script on a webpage you visit is allowed to execute on your machine, browser storage doesn't provide any mechanisms that would require the script to pass an step access to them. But, then again, at that point nothing else does without a lot of extra hassle for both the end user and the developer
It could be encrypted and then stored which would make it a bit more secure so long as your app doesn't need any of that info. Otherwise you'll need to store the encryption key or whatever in your spa. And that same key would be accessible to anyone using the app. But for the ones you mentioned, only the specific user and from specific origins is quite a bit of security for SPAs.
